# How to push my Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have made changes to the database I need to migrate.

After commiting my changes to github with no problem, when I attempt to push my app to Heroku using

```
push heroku master
```

I receive several error messages on the command line.

```
Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.14.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
```

As the error bedug instructs, I ran

```
gem install bundler
```

and then it gave me a second error:

```
WARNING:
remote: No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote: We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile
devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
```

I followed the instructions on the website in the link attached, but didn't resolve the problem.

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something in the bigger picture?

Background/more info: I migrated my database to Heroku in the past with no problem, added a method to products and then got so many errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWqYp.png)

Comment: do you get an actual error? these are warnings and theoretically would not stop your app from running.

Comment: do you mean running the app like it migrating to Heroku?
The database changes have not migrated to the app on heroku

Comment: i mean running the app on heroku. so it's a database issue? because once you push to heroku, you need to run your migrations again: `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Don't use links to images to convey information essential to the problem. Copy and paste the _relevant and significant_ parts into the question. This lets us reuse the text without typing it in, and search engines can index the information and help others find the answers given. SO is about the future searchers and you're helping write an article how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku restricts the version of Bundler that your app can use in production. Even if your version is newer - it will generate the above message.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version

As for Procfile message - that's generated because your attempting to install a server gem (most likely Puma) that requires the file to run on Heroku instead of Webrick. Webrick is generally considered unsuitable for production use because it can't accept a large volume of incoming requests at once.

Follow instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server if you're attempting to run Puma.

Comment: NIce. But should I set a version of bundler in my Gemfile to avoid having two different bundler gem versions between development and production? thanks

Comment: You can, depending on platform and preference. I've had no issues, however.

Answer (score 0):

On your bundler error, you should be able to safely ignore it (since you're getting a warning and not a true error). See the [Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version).

On your procfile error, visit the article referenced or read about [Process Types and the Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). Again, you can safely ignore this warning and Heroku will boot up using the default web server (Webrick, I believe).